# typescript syntax - how to single line filter/map array

Tags: javascript, typescript

many times I need to loop arrays to get only specific items inside that.

here's an example:

```
let girls = [];
this.kidsArray.forEach(function(v){
  if(v['genre'] == 'f'){
    girls.push(v.id);
  }
});
```

so, is there any simpler/cleaner way to do this? maybe with filter/map array methods, or something like that?

Comment: use `array.filter` method [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Comment: let kidsArray = [{name:'vinod',gender:'M'},{name:'harini',gender:'F'},{name:'Lalitha',gender:'F'}];
kidsArray = kidsArray.filter(v=>v.gender=='M');
console.log(kidsArray);